# Broken recovery mod!

Tags: updates, recovery-mode, boot-loop

My Sk17i phone(Mini pro) is rooted. And used CWM to install a custom "Unlimited" Rom, then restarted after installation.

And now my handset keeps boot-looping.

After I tried to *fast boot*, before opening/unlocking boot loader.

PC companion can not find software, SEUS does not update the ROM, as SEUS says its already up to date.

The CWM Recovery saved my data, How can I view it?

Comment: I cannot tell from this question if you can boot back in to the recovery, if you can, try wiping data and cache. if that doesn't work, are you sure you installed a ROM for your specific device?

Comment: Rom Sk17i Unlimited rom.
I'm setup recovery before installing... Backup sys,data,cache.
Rom setup>reset>Boot logo,Stay... 
I can not access the recovery menu!!!!

Comment: Fastboot cmd>Fastboot flash system system.img
< Waiting for Device > !!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you ask for but

> The CWM Recovery saved my data, How can I view it?

if you mean backups, they'd be in your SD card.

> Fastboot cmd>Fastboot flash system system.img < Waiting for Device > !!

that usually means a driver problem IF you can boot into bootloader properly.

[Interesting link with un-bricking guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1568792)

Comment: Reinstall driver,and try again?
Sorry,I'm not speed good english,i'm hungary

Comment: yes, try that.
also read the link I gave.
igen, próbáld ezt.
is olvastam a linket adtam.

Comment: pls link driver package! Thx